# Dynamically set image of each node

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, datatemplate, datatrigger

So I have 3 levels of nodes in my TreeView:

- A single Root Node (should display Image1.png)
- Some second level nodes (should display Image2.png)
- Each second level node has some third-level nodes (should display Image3.png)

I'm trying to use a `DataTemplate` to dynamically assign the display image to each node, depending upon its *level*. Since level is not as easily available in WPF as it is in WinForms, I simply resorted to using `Tag` property of `TreeViewItem`s to store their level. Then I wrote this following `Style` for assigning display images:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Name="img" Width="20" Height="20" Stretch="Fill">
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag}" Value="0">
                                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="Icons\Image1.png"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag}" Value="1">
                                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="Icons\Image2.png"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" Margin="5,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Yes, you guessed it; it doesn't work. Can someone please identify where the problem lies? Or am I doing it just the wrong way?

Comment: Tag is not a property of the object in the TreeViewItem's DataContext. You should set a RelativeSource on `{Binding Tag}`.

Comment: @Clemens: I changed that to `Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Tag}"`, but it still doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, your {Binding Tag} will try to find the Tag property of the TreeViewItem's DataContext, not the DependencyProperty. And since, i'm guessing, there is no Tag property in the DataContext, it won't work. If you look at your output Windows in VS, you should see binding errors all over the place.

What you need to do is add the relative source to your binding so it looks at the TreeViewItem instead of the DataContext. Here is an example :

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}" Value="0">
```